# Create dummy variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to create a dummy variable when querying

For instance the query below will give me only the observations that satisfy the var1 conditions. I also want the remaining observations but with some kind of tag on it (0/1, indicator values would be sufficient)

```
SELECT distinct ON (id) id,var1,var2,var3 
FROM table 
where var2 = ANY('{blue,yellow}');
```

Have

```
    +-----+------+--------+------+
    | id  | Var1 |  Var2  | Var3 |
    +-----+------+--------+------+
    | 345 |   12 | Blue   | 3456 |
    | 345 |   12 | Red    | 2134 |
    | 346 |   45 | Blue   | 3451 |
    | 347 |   25 | yellow | 1526 |
    +-----+------+--------+------+
```

Want

```
+-----+------+--------+------+--------------------+
| id  | Var1 |  Var2  | Var3 | Indicator variable |
+-----+------+--------+------+--------------------+
| 345 |   12 | Blue   | 3456 |                  1 |
| 345 |   12 | Red    | 2134 |                  0 |
| 346 |   45 | Blue   | 3451 |                  1 |
| 347 |   25 | yellow | 1526 |                  1 |
+-----+------+--------+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen. Can you provide a sample input and explain what you want the desired output to be?

Comment: Added tables, I hope this is possible

Comment: Tometzky's answer should get you want you want.  If you want something more complex (i.e. not just a boolean) then you probably want to use case statements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a expression in `where` you can use an expression in select output expressions:

```
=> select a, a = any('{1,2,3,5,7}') as asmallprime
    from generate_series(1,10) as a;
 a  | asmallprime 
----+-------------
  1 | t
  2 | t
  3 | t
  4 | f
  5 | t
  6 | f
  7 | t
  8 | f
  9 | f
 10 | f
(10 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tometzky's answer is sufficient, but if you want something more complex you can also use CASE statements.

Tometzky's example using CASE with an extra indicator

```
SELECT a, CASE WHEN a = any('{1,2,3,5,7}') THEN 'YES' 
  WHEN a = any('{4,9}') THEN 'SQUARE' ELSE 'NO' END as asmallprime
FROM generate_series(1,10) as a;
```